# azure devop project stats longer than 30 days?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In azure devop, we can see the project stats, for example this one. But it is only showing upto 30 days activities.

I am wondering if there is a way (maybe some API call) to show activities over a whole year? We area trying to do a end of year report for big boss and would be nice to show how many deployments we done,how many PR were completed etc over the whole year.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By checking the API that it called behind the scenes, you should have something like

```
https://ORG.visualstudio.com/GUI/_apis/build/Metrics/Daily?minMetricsTime=2021-11-05T13%3A08%3A08.556Z
```

You can manipulate this value on browser and change the date to an older one for example *(2020-12-16)*

As I am not working with an Azure Devops repos for long time I cannot test the behavior, but it maybe work.

[image: browser request]

Comment: Let me try this, never heard about this org metrics api before

Comment: turned out I don't even have permission to access this api, so can't really try this for now

Comment: @daxu you should be logged in on the Azure Devops organization. This API is triggered on your browser when you see the stats on the main page of the project, as a result you should be able to access it

Comment: I did, it throws this {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user '82f41f1b-d00f-4f7b-a740-e0fd8515f272\\xxx.yyy.com' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}